# Fullscreen Gap in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, resolution, fullscreen

I have two different monitors on my computer with Windows 10. They have entirely different resolutions. The left one is set at `1920 x 1080` and the right one is at `1680 x 1050`. The right one is the main monitor.

However, whenever I put anything in Chrome into full screen on the left monitor, there's a thin gap, about 10-20 pixels, along the top and left, where I can see my desktop background. So "Full Screen" doesn't actually consume the entire screen.

[image: Full screen gap]

I can't really set both monitors to the same resolution; not without them either stretching or leaving the black area on either side of the screen. Otherwise, I'm sure if both were the same resolution, it would probably work, just as it works fine back at my work computer with a similar setup, but with identical monitors. Just, here at home, I have two entirely different monitors.

How can I fix this so that fullscreen will always consume the entire screen?

Comment: For me problem gone when I made the browser not maximized (floating window) on that monitor.
Also in my case, two monitors have seme resolution, but I had the same problem. And yes, Chrome has a theme applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same issue for awhile now and finally found that resetting my theme in Chrome to default solved it for me.

1. Open Settings or navigate to "chrome://settings/"
2. Under the third section called "Appearance", hit the "Reset to default theme" button

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmmm, and I do have a theme that I love so much :-/

Comment: Yeah, me too. T_T

Comment: Seems to be that most themes aren't 100% compatible. The very top area, where there are no tabs hasn't been themed by most themes on wide monitors. Maybe this is a Chrome bug and isn't part of the themeing package?